# i want to slice my array for a search, but using array.split() it return a object

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an input that at each keyup it executes the search function going through an array, I want to break the strings of my array into a string for each letter.

ex: i type "i" the function takes my div and innerHTML on every string in the original array that has "i"

the input that I get the value:

```html
<input type="text" id="name-catch"> <!--input for search-->
```

the div that I pass the innerHTML with the value of the original array:

```html
<div class="show-client"></div>
```

The eventListener that im using:

```js
document.querySelector('#name-catch').addEventListener('keyup', ()=>{
event.preventDefault()

var res = document.querySelector('div.show-client')


var valor = document.querySelector('#name-catch').value
var nameSearch = valor.toUpperCase()

for(pos = 0; pos<nume.length; pos++){
        if(nameSearch === nume[pos]){
            console.log('cliente encontrado', nume[pos])
            res.innerHTML += nume[pos]
            res.style.display = 'flex'

            pos += 10 //my array has names, data and numbers in strings. each name (value I want to compare with input) is after 10
        }else{
            console.log('jogando no else')
            res.style.display = 'none'
            res.innerHTML = ''
        }
})
```

Comment: what's your array looks like?

Comment: You are talking about using `split()` but I don't see a call to `split` in your code

Comment: @spikef thats my array:
` let nume = [
       ''name'', ''jessica'',
       ''cpf'', ''number'',
       ''plano'', ''number''
`

all values ​​I get by input